# Animate partial view from AJAX-call

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have this code for rendering a partial view:

```
$(".user").click(function () {

        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/ShowUser?xid=" + id,
            contentType: 'application/html; charset-utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        })
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#showuser').html(result); //<-Add an effect?

            });
    });
```

Is it possible to use something like jquery slideDown or soething like that in order to animate the partial?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First slidUp your #showuser div on document.ready event and then slideDown it after ajax success i.e:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#showuser').slideUp();

    $(".user").click(function () {

            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/ShowUser?xid=" + id,
                contentType: 'application/html; charset-utf-8',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                .success(function (result) {
                    $('#showuser').html(result);           // first setting html
                    $('#showuser').slideDown(500);         // then sliding it down
                });
    });

)};
```